# Javascript login page with Python Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to login to the following page using Python selenium package to do few activities. I wrote the following, but every time I  get "the Class is not found". I need to access the username and password to use `send_keys()`. Any feedback on this is appreciated.

[Code]

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/vbabu/AppData/Local/chromedriver')
chrome_browser.maximize_window()
chrome_browser.get('https://myservices-dfsi.console.oraclecloud.com/mycloud/cloudportal/gettingStarted')

form = chrome_browser.find_element_by_id('idcs-signin-basic-signin-form-post-redirect-form')
print(form)
```

[Error]

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="idcs-signin-basic-signin-form-post-redirect-form"]"}

[Expected Output]

I need to access the username and password tags.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: maybe wait few second until it will load all code and run JavaScript - at least try `time.sleep(5)`

Comment: element selected on your image has different ID then you use in code.

Comment: code works for me  if I use `time.sleep(3)` before `find_element_by_id()`

Comment: @furas - Thanks . That did the trick. I realised that i highlighted the wrong tag in the screenshot. my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using explicit wait until element get available to perform actions

```
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "idcs-signin-basic-signin-form-username")))
username.send_keys("some_text")
```

import below packages:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I tried using your method and it gives me the following error
'''
 username = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.ID, "idcs-signin-basic-signin-form-username"))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
'''

Comment: My bad i forgot `()`. now updated the answer. please try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

`time.sleep(5)`
and `ID = "idcs-signin-basic-signin-form-username"`